# Crystal Reports Server 2013 - RPT file location

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

I have my Crystal Reports server configured against an Oracle data source, but now I need to switch it to be configured against a SQL Server data source, on a different server. This server has no way to communicate with the original server to use the import tool.

I was looking into how to import the data myself. Looking at the tables, I see that it stores binary fields in the database. Are the reports stored as binary data inside the data source, or does each RPT file has a copy somewhere on the disk? If it is on the disk where? If it's inside the data source binary field, does importing the data to a new server will still work?

Answer (score 0):

The CCM (*Central Configuration Manager*) – not to be confused with the CMS – has the ability to migrate your database repository from one database to another, even if the database vendor differs (i.e. Oracle vs. Microsoft).

Have a look at the administrator guide, the procedure is described in chapter 11, *Managing Central Management Server (CMS) Databases*, section 4 *Copying data from one CMS system database to another*.

A small excerpt:

> You can use the Central Configuration Manager (CCM) or cmsdbsetup.sh
>   to copy system data from one database server into another database
>   server. For example, if you want to replace the database with another
>   database because you are upgrading the database or are moving from one
>   database type to another, you can copy the contents of the existing
>   database into the new database before decommissioning the existing
>   database.

Regarding the reports themselves, they are not stored in the database, but in the file repository. However, you need to view the database and file repository as one: the first contains the metadata while the latter contains the actual files. However, they can not function separately.

In other words, you cannot just copy the RPT files from the file repository to another server and expect them to work, as the information that is contained in the metadata (such as authorisations) will be missing. On the other hand, if you just copy the database repository but omit the file repository, you'll end up with all the information regarding your reports, but you won't be able to open or run them.